# Not able to get data from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

There is a php file which queries the MySql database to get some info, but the else statement seems to execute whatever the condition.

```
require_once("../sqli_connect.php");

$id = $_GET["id"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id=".$id;

//echo $query."<br>";

$response = @mysqli_connect($dbc, $query);

if($response){
    $row = $response->fetch_assoc();

    echo "<h2>".$row["post_subject"]."</h2>";
    echo "<h4>".$row["post_by"]."</h4>";
    echo "<div>".$row["post_content"]."</div>";
}
else{
    echo "no response";
}
```

I have even tried to change post_id in the query to a constant id like 1 or 2.

But I still don't see the issue!

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
not error but bug.

Comment: whats the error said?

Comment: it executes the else statement

Comment: you are missing a closing `"` from the end of the sql statement and not executing the sql

Comment: When you use `@` in front of anything, in this case `@mysqli_connect`, it can hide important error messages from you. You should handle errors differently.

Comment: Hi,
First of all, remove the "@" at "@mysqli_connect".
It won't return any error if you use "@"

Comment: RamRider sorry that was a typo in the question not the code!

Comment: ERROR: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: Syntax error `$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id=".$id.";` - *"Edit: not error but bug."* - Error, syntax error. ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ besides not querying.

Comment: @Webster It wouldn't return any error anyway. It will return an object, on any case. To check for errors, he has to check the `connect_error` variable of the `mysqli` instance.

Comment: Please note that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections. Please use Prepared Statements with binding parameters.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois 
   
ERROR: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: @Michael you are modifying code in your suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11002555 - I rejected it. We are NOT to modify code here. Most likely that is what the OP is really using.

Comment: @pradyumna rahul and you approved the edit. df? so why didn't you post your REAL code in the first place. Making comments useless now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- noted. Although in this case it could be seen by the description that it was a typo. But point taken. Will not do it again.

Comment: @Michael [See my comment here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966009/not-able-to-get-data-from-mysql-database/34966080?noredirect=1#comment57662829_34966080) under Rajdeep's answer. That will answer y'all ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this statement here,

```
$response = @mysqli_connect($dbc, $query);
```

You're not executing the query. It should be,

```
$response = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

And use `mysqli_num_rows()` function to check if it returns any row or not. So your code should be like this:

```
<?php

    require_once("../sqli_connect.php");

    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id={$id}";

    $response = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($response)){
        while($row = $response->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<h2>".$row["post_subject"]."</h2>";
            echo "<h4>".$row["post_by"]."</h4>";
            echo "<div>".$row["post_content"]."</div>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "no response";
    }

?>
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
- [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: and that `$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id=".$id.";` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OP approved an *edit* in the midway. Now a days it's hard to say whether it's a typo by OP or an actual error. BTW I didn't notice that, thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: I never approve edits as such, unless a person has been *specifically* asked by the OP to make the edit. It could have an adverse effect on people submitting answers where they would base themselves on that, and in turn possibly being downvoted for it if/when an edit is approved. I have seen this happen many times; *call it experience* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that you now have an answer to the problem and what follows is slightly off target from what has been accepted but nobody has mentioned the possibility of sql injection here so this might be useful to you at some point.

It uses an OO approach to the mysqli operations and utilises `prepare statements`

```
/* connection parameters */
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';  

$conn = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

if( $conn ){
    /* assuming id is an integer */
    $id=!empty( $_GET['id'] ) ? intval( $_GET['id'] ) : false;

    if( $id ){
        /* set fields to be returned - variables are matched to placeholders `?` */
        $sql='SELECT `post_subject`,`post_by`,`post_content` FROM `post` WHERE `post_id`=?';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

        /* bind user supplied variable in a safe manner */
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id );
        $res=$stmt->execute();

        if( $res ){
            /* prepare output variables */
            $stmt->bind_result( $subject, $by, $content );

            while( $stmt->fetch() ){/* iterate through recordset */
                echo "
                <h2>{$subject}</h2>
                <h4>{$by}</h4>
                <div>{$content}</div>"; 
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No response'; 
        }
    } else {
        echo 'missing id';  
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```